# Java: Printing all unique unordered pairs with nested (quadratic) loop using iterator

Tags: java, iterator, nested-loops

The following code prints all unique unordered pairs of a given list.

```
//Input: List containing {a, b, c, d, e}
//Output: (a, b) (a, c) (a, d) (a, e) (b, c) (b, d) (b, e) (c, d) (c, e) (d, e)

private static void pairs(List<Character> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++){
            System.out.print("("+list.get(i)+", "+list.get(j)+") ");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do the same thing using iterators as using "get" would be really bad if the list is LinkedList. I'm having trouble with the *j = i + 1* part. The code I'm looking for probably should look something like this.

```
private static void pairs2(List<Character> list) {
    Iterator<Character> iter1 = list.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()){
        char char1 = iter1.next().charValue();
        Iterator<Character> iter2 = ???;
        while (iter2.hasNext()){
            char char2 = iter2.next().charValue();
            System.out.print("("+char1+", "+char2+") ");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit for future reference: As suggested bellow seems that the best way is to use ListIterator instead of Iterator.

```
ListIterator <Character> iter1 = list.listIterator();
...
ListIterator<Character> iter2 = list.listIterator(iter1.nextIndex());
```

Comment: Why don't you just copy `iter1` into `iter2`?  Or if you can't do that, do `.next().prev()`.

Comment: You could make a copy of the list and use the copy for your other iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `ListIterator` rather than a normal `Iterator` via `list.listIterator()`, you can get its index via `iter1.nextIndex()`. Then you can start `iter2` as `list.listIterator(index)` from that position.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create another iterator

```
int count = 0;
while(iter1.hasNext()){
    count++;
    char char1 = iter1.next().charValue();
    Iterator<Character> iter2 = list.iterator();
    //Skip first count elements
    for(int j; j<count; j++){
         iter2.next();
    }
    while (iter2.hasNext()){
        char char2 = iter2.next().charValue();
        System.out.print("("+char1+", "+char2+") ");
    }
}
```

You can have several of them simultaneously.

Comment: that would be equivalent to writing j = 0 instead of j = i + 1 in the first piece of code. this mean double run time with no reason and adding additional code to check the positions of the second iterator. isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Oops. Didn't saw it. In this case Iterator is not a good choice. You steel can do it, But you need to count how many item you process in outer loop and skip them in inner loop.